# What are the differences between Spring MVC and Struts?

Tags: spring

Both Spring MVC and Strut's are almost similar. But Spring MVC is loosely coupled and Struts is tightly coupled. 

Is this the only major difference between them? Could anybody explain me the Struts framework comparing with Spring MVC side by side?

Comment: This is far too broad for this site. You'd better google for *SpringMVC vs Struts*, or even better use tutorials to build sample application for both frameworks and make your own opinion.

Comment: Yeah i have searched many related topics but was not able to find struts explained comparing Spring MVC side by side instead it was Struts a separate topic.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/struts-2-vs-springmvc-know-the-difference-choose-t

Comment: I agree that this question is a bit too broad. Maybe you could detail which framework do you know and how much, and also why are you asking this question (you're creating an app, starting advanced java studying, or something ?)

Comment: Actually i want to convert the application which is on Struts framework to Spring MVC and as i know spring MVC framework only so it is insufficient for achieving this task. Moreover, understanding the new Struts framework as a whole new topic is more complex task for me than understanding it by comparing with the framework which i know that is Spring MVC.

Comment: Struts and SpringMVC do have different internals, so you should not try to convert element by element. You'd better write a new controller layer from scratch, based on the observable behaviour of the application.

Answer (score 1):

One major difference from my point of view, is that Struts is (i believe) only configurable via XML, when SpringMVC make good use of annotation or JavaConfig.

For more information, Google provide a large choice of result that compare them.
Just search "Spring MVC vs Struts"

Comment: When using Convention Plugin the action mapping can be configured with annotations. Please see [action-configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html)

Answer (score -1):

Both spring MVC and Struts are framework which does same work but having bit difference between them.Major difference between Spring MVC and Struts is that Spring MVC is loosely coupled framework while Struts is tightly coupled. For enterprise Application you need to build your application as loosely coupled as it would make your application more reusable and robust as well as distributed.